# Python function calling with variable vs raw numbers

Tags: python, particle-swarm

I am trying to implement a pso algorithm from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization.

My problem is that when I am calling the cost function with a variable (Gbest), and then manually calling the cost function (with the Gbest data) I get a different output (cost) like the image bellow:
[Code fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MUwJ.png)

I am new to python so thank you for any suggestions.

Here is the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from control.matlab import *

A = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,2,-2]])
B = np.array( [[0],[1],[0]])
C = np.array([[0, 1,0]])
D = np.zeros([C.shape[0],B.shape[1]])
sys = ss(A,B,C,D)


sys_tf = tf(sys)
s = tf('s')


def cost(kp,ki):
    global sys_tf, G, y, t, r
    G = kp + ki/s

    C = feedback(sys_tf*G, 1)
    y, t = step(C, linspace(0,100))
    r = np.ones(len(t))
    return np.sum(y-r)**2



part = 100
ite = 10000
dim = 2

w = 0.001
wdamp = 0.99

phip = 0.9
phig = 0.1

blo, bup = -10,10

x = np.zeros([dim, part])
v = np.zeros([dim, part])
pbest = np.zeros([dim, part])
gbest = np.array([1000000,1000000])

for i in range(part):
    for k in range(dim):
        x[k][i] = pbest[k][i] = np.random.uniform(blo, bup)
        v[k][i] = np.random.uniform(-np.abs(bup - blo), np.abs(bup - blo))
    

if cost(pbest[0][i], pbest[1][i]) < cost(gbest[0], gbest[1]):
    gbest = np.array([pbest[0][i], pbest[1][i]])

for it in range(ite):
    for i in range(part):
        for k in range(dim):
            rp = np.random.uniform(0,1)
            rg = np.random.uniform(0,1)

            v[k,:] = w*v[k,:] + phip*rp*(pbest[k,:] - x[k,:]) + phig*rg*(gbest[k] - x[k,:])
            x[k,:] = x[k,:] + v[k,:]
            w = w*wdamp


        if cost(x[0][i], x[1][i]) < cost(pbest[0][i], pbest[1][i]):
            pbest[:,i] = x[:,i]
            if cost(pbest[0][i], pbest[1][i]) < cost(gbest[0], gbest[1]):
                gbest = np.array([pbest[0][i], pbest[1][i]])
    plt.plot(t, y, 'ro')
    plt.plot(t, r, 'x')
    plt.pause(0.005)
    plt.title(gbest)
    print([gbest, cost(gbest[0], gbest[1])])
```

Comment: The cost function is using global variables, which it changes, so I suspect if you call it twice with the same inputs you will get different outputs. Also, maybe try it with one particle to see what that does - this may help you debug.

Comment: @doctorlove global variables of the cost function are just coefficients that don't change through iterations, they remain constant throughout the program.

Comment: I wondered if `G = kp + ki/s` changed `G`

Comment: @doctorlove That's the thing I have different values for the cost function for the same input(kp,ki) as you can see in the picture uploaded